# Trouble getting text in to an email

Tags: python

I'm trying to send an email to someone with information I've scraped from the web but I can't get the contents to send. I keep receiving empty emails. Any help would be great. I've tried all sorts of different numbers of ' and +s and i can't figure it out.

```
def singaporeweather():
    singaporehigh=singapore_soup.find(class_='tab-temp-high').text
    singaporelow=singapore_soup.find(class_='tab-temp-low').text
    print('There will be highs of ' + singaporehigh + ' and lows of ' + 
    singaporelow + '.')

def singaporesuns():
    singaporesunsets=singapore_soup.find(class_='row col-sm-5')
    suns_singapore=singaporesunsets.find_all('time')
    sunset_singapore=suns_singapore[1].text
    sunrise_singapore=suns_singapore[0].text
    print('Sunrise: ' + sunrise_singapore)
    print('Sunset: ' + sunset_singapore)


def ukweather():
    ukhigh= uk_soup.find('span', class_='tab-temp-high').text
    uklow= uk_soup.find(class_='tab-temp-low').text
    print('There will be highs of ' + ukhigh + ' and lows of ' + uklow + 
    '.')

def uksuns():
    uk_humid = uk_soup.find('div', class_='row col-sm-5')
    humidity=uk_humid.find_all('time')
    sunrise_uk=humidity[0].text
    sunset_uk= humidity[1].text
    print('Sunrise: '+str(sunrise_uk))
    print('Sunset: '+str(sunset_uk))

def ukdesc():
    uk_desc=uk_soup.find('div',class_='summary-text hide-xs-only')
    uk_desc_2=uk_desc.find('span')
    print(uk_desc_2.text)`enter code here`

def quotes():
    quote_text=quote_soup.find(class_='b-qt qt_914910 oncl_q').text
    author=quote_soup.find(class_='bq-aut qa_914910 oncl_a').text
    print('Daily quote:\n' + '\"'+quote_text +'\"'+ ' - ' + author +'\n')





def message():
    print('Subject:Testing\n\n')
    print(('Morning ' + 
    nameslist[random.randint(1(len(nameslist)-1))]).center(30,'*'), 
    end='\n'*2)

    quotes()

    print('UK'.center(30,'_') + '\n')
    ukweather()
    ukdesc()
    uksuns()

    print('\n' + 'Singapore'.center(30,'_') + '\n')
    singaporeweather()
    singaporedesc()
    singaporesuns()

smtpthing.sendmail('XXX@outlook.com', 'XXX@bath.ac.uk', str(message()))
```

Comment: You define lots of functions but never call them?

Comment: The "message" function (as the other ones) only print things but don't return anything.

Answer (score 2):

In your functions, instead of printing the results to the console, you should use `return` statements so that you can use the function's result in your main program. Otherwise, `message()` is returning null, which is why your email is empty (the main program cannot see `message()`'s result unless it is returned).

Try something like:

```
def singaporeweather():
    singaporehigh=singapore_soup.find(class_='tab-temp-high').text
    singaporelow=singapore_soup.find(class_='tab-temp-low').text
    return 'There will be highs of ' + singaporehigh + ' and lows of ' + 
    singaporelow + '.'
```

By using a return statement like this one, you will be able to use `singaporeweather()`'s result in your main program, e.g.:

```
var result = singaporeweather()
```

Using `return`s in the rest of your methods as well, you will be able to do the following in your function `message()`:

```
def message():
    body = "" #your message
    body += 'Subject:Testing\n\n'
    body += ('Morning ' + nameslist[random.randint(1(len(nameslist)-1))]).center(30,'*')

    body += quotes()

    body += 'UK'.center(30,'_') + '\n'
     + ukweather()
     + ukdesc()
     + uksuns()

     + '\n' + 'Singapore'.center(30,'_') + '\n'
     + singaporeweather()
     + singaporedesc()
     + singaporesuns()

    #finally, don't forget to return!
    return body
```

Now you are returning `body`, now you can use `message()`'s result in your main program to send your email correctly:

```
smtpthing.sendmail('XXX@outlook.com', 'XXX@bath.ac.uk', str(message()))
```